# How to avoid Kafka consumer processing old messages in retry queue

Tags: apache-kafka

Given we use Kafka to update product information in our system.

1. A new message to update the price of a product is not processed correctly and it's sent to a retry topic that has a 10min delay.
2. In the next minute a new message to update the price of the same product is sent and correctly consumed.
3. The old message from the retry topic is consumed, leaving the product with the old price instead of the current one.

How is it possible to avoid this scenario in Kafka?

Comment: Can this be solved by checking on updated_at column of the product in the DB before updating it and if this value is greater than the timestamp of the kafka message we don't update the product and skip to the next message?

Comment: Kafka is unaware of the context of the message. It's job is to a broker between producer and consumer. Also, dead queue concept is generally less used in kafka. Just don't commit offset that failed to process.

Comment: @themoah Dead-letter topics are definitely used in Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to track what has been consumed somewhere.

A KTable might be able to do this (lookup record by key, if the table has the key, then it has already been consumed and processed... meaning you'd have a simple "processed" topic next to your "retry" topic), but if you have an external DB, then that will work as well. Main downside is that you will be introducing an external dependency, and it will slow down your processing as every incoming event will need to query the database.